# How do I make the value of this field just NULL

Tags: c++, vb6, null

```
        char *k_Account;
```

I want to make that above have a NULL value how do I do that in VB6 C++?

Comment: Are you writing in C++ or VB6? They are completely different languages, and the answer is therefore different.

Comment: Is there anything special about (I assume you meant to say VC6) that none of the normal ways work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the following way

```
char *k_Account = NULL;
```

Or if your compiler has no the definition of NULL then you can write

```
char *k_Account = ( void * )0;
```

Also it seems you trying to initialize the pointer which is a data member of some class.

If you have an old compiler then you may not write for example as

```
struct A
{
   char *k_Account = NULL;
};
```

However you have two approaches. the first is to initialize the data member in a constructor. For example

```
struct A
{
   A() {  k_Account = NULL; }
   char *k_Account;
};
```

Or if the mem initializer list is supported then you can write

```
struct A
{
   A() : k_Account( NULL ) {}
   char *k_Account;
};
```

If your class has no constructor and has only public non-static members and has no virtual function and a base class then you can initialize the pointer when you create an object of the class

For example

```
struct A
{
   char *k_Account;
};

A a = { NULL };
```

Comment: Technically, `(void *)0` is not a legal definition for `NULL` in C++. It must be an integral constant that evaluates to 0.

Comment: @chris You are wrong. This code is correct. You may assign null pointer to pointer of any type and it wiill be null pointer of this type.

Comment: that gives this error when I build the .exe:   error C2252: 'k_Account' : pure specifier can only be specified for functions

Comment: error C2252 pure specifier can only be specified for functions –

Comment: @user3352532 I think it is a result of some other error. At least the statement you showed shall not generate the error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I'm not saying the code is wrong, I'm just saying that it's not a perfect replacement for `NULL`.

Comment: @user3352532, I'm assuming you have this in a class. Use a constructor initializer list.

Comment: @user3352532  Try to prepare a simple exmple that can be compiled as is and demonstrates the problem.